# Rspec let symbol created from an array changes both when the copy is modified

Tags: ruby, rspec

I'm new to ruby/rspec and am having trouble finding this answer, likely because I'm not quite sure how to word it.

I have a test that looks something like the following and just tries to change a value of a symbol created with `let` from a predefined array

```rb
describe 'changing hash' do
  let(:array_a) do
    #create array that looks like:
    # [{:title=>'first', :position=>0}, {:title=>'second', :position=>1}]
  end

  context 'when changing values of array b' do
    let(:array_b) {array_a}
    it 'array a doesnt change'
      #Swap title of first and second object
      temp_title = array_b[0][:title]
      array_b[0][:title] = array_b[1][:title]
      array_b[1][:title] = temp_slug

      expect(array_b).not_to eq(array_a)
      #The above doesn't fails because array_a[0][:title] has *also* been changed.
    end
  end
end
```

When I log `array_a` and `array_b` after modifying `array_b`, they both look the same (both having their 0'th index have a title of 'second'

Why is this happening and how do I create a copy that I can modify without modifying the original it was copied from?

Comment: `array_b` is `array_a` based on the way you defined them `let(:array_b) {array_a}` is essentially `def array_b; @array_b ||= array_a; end`

Comment: @engineersmnky ty, how would I then make a copy of array_a that I can then modify?

Comment: Making a "copy" is interesting because mechanism2 like `dup` and `clone` are shallow. e.g. `array_b = array_a.dup` results in `b.equal?(a) #=> false` but `b[0].equal?(a[0]) #=> true`. You could do `array_b = array_a.map(&:dup)` which solves the previous 2 concerns however it does not solve that `array_b[0][:title].equal?(array_a[0][:title])`....

Comment: ...One of the simplest ways to make a fully independent copy would be to dump and then load the object e.g. `let(:array_b) { Marshal.load(Marshal.dump(array_a))}` by doing this array_b and array_a will not share any of the same objects but this only works on objects that can be marshaled, so for your case this would be fine.

Comment: @engineersmnky thank you, this worked perfectly. I'll look more into this

Comment: I also found that `.deep_dup` worked as well

Comment: `deep_dup` is part of Rails but not part of ruby core but yes if you are using Rails then that will work.